# List of all of concurrent data structures added in .net 4?

Tags: .net, .net-4.0, concurrency, task-parallel-library, concurrent-programming

Is there a comprehensive list of all new concurrent data structures added in .net 4?  Or perhaps the list of namespaces like System.Collections.Concurrent?

Comment: I can't give you a list of specifically the concurrent data structures, but there's a good overview of .NET 4.0 changes here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms171868.aspx.  And http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff641764.aspx has a list of all the new types and members. I suspect that most of what you're looking for is in `System.Collections.Concurrent` and `System.Threading.Tasks`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd460718.aspx

This is a complete lists for new data structures for parallel programming, that includes:

- Concurrent Collection Classes
- Synchronization Primitives
- Lazy Initialization Classes
- Aggregate Exceptions

Answer (score 0):

I believe it is just the collections found in [System.Collections.Concurrent](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.concurrent.aspx).